# python sys.exit not working in try

Tags: python, python-2.7, redhat, exit

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 26 2014, 13:43:17)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...  sys.exit()
... except:
...  print "in except"
...
in except
>>> try:
...  sys.exit(0)
... except:
...  print "in except"
...
in except
>>> try:
...  sys.exit(1)
... except:
...  print "in except"
...
in except
```

Why am not able to trigger sys.exit() in try, any suggestions...!!!

The code posted here has all the version details.

I have tried all possible ways i know to trigger it, but i failed.
It gets to 'except' block.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, because the other post explains a) what goes wrong and b) how to avoid this. Blanket `except:` clauses are not a good idea, at best use `except Exception:` to avoid catching `SystemExit`.

Comment: use os._exit(0) if you don't want to trigger an exception.

Comment: @Back2Basics: **Don't** call `os._exit()`; that just ensures nothing gets cleaned up as the processor exits.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`sys.exit()` raises an exception, namely `SystemExit`. That's why you land in the `except`-block.

See this example:

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit()
except:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
```

This gives you:

```
<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>
```

Although I can't imagine that one has any practical reason to do so, you can use this construct:

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit() # this always raises SystemExit
except SystemExit:
    print("sys.exit() worked as expected")
except:
    print("Something went horribly wrong") # some other exception got raised
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in try block.

Comment: There is no reason, since what you try to achieve is raising an exception in `try` and "catch" it in the next moment. It is absolutely clueless ;-)

Comment: Use `except Exception`, because `SystemExit` inherits directly from `BaseException`. See the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks buddy..!! If u come across any idea regarding this, plz do update me.

Comment: See the updated code example to achieve what you wanted. However, still no idea why you would do that.

Comment: @onlyvinish He already gave you an idea! What else are you missing?

Answer (score 12):

based on python wiki :

> Since [exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.

And:

> The `exit` function is not called when the program is killed by a signal, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when `os._exit()` is called.

Therefore, If you use `sys.exit()` within a `try` block python after raising the `SystemExit` exception python refuses of completing the `exits`'s functionality and executes the `exception` block.

Now, from a programming perspective you basically don't need to put something that you know definitely raises an exception in a `try` block. Instead you can either raise a [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception manually or as a more Pythonic approach if you don't want to loose the respective functionalities of `sys.exit()` like passing optional argument to its constructor you can call `sys.exit()` in a `finally`, `else` or even `except` block.

Method 1 (not recommended)

```
try:
    # do stuff
except some_particular_exception:
    # handle this exception and then if you want 
    # do raise SystemExit
else:
    # do stuff and/or do raise SystemExit
finally:
    # do stuff and/or do raise SystemExit
```

Method 2 (Recommended):

```
try:
    # do stuff
except some_particular_exception:
    # handle this exception and then if you want 
    # do sys.exit(stat_code)
else:
    # do stuff and/or do sys.exit(stat_code)
finally:
    # do stuff and/or do sys.exit(stat_code)
```

Comment: Don't call `os._exit()` yourself, *just don't catch `SystemExit`*. Calling `os._exit()` means nothing gets cleaned up either.