# exit(0) within try block not exiting the program

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to exit the program if a condition has been met. The condition is in a `try` block.
Here is my code:

```
import time

a=1

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        if a==1:
            print("exiting")
            exit(0)
        else:
            print("in else")
    except:
        print("in except")
```

instead of exiting it is printing:

```
exiting
in except
exiting
in except
exiting
in except
exiting
in except
.
.
.
```

Any explanation?

Comment: You're trapping all exceptions, including the `SystemExit` exception, so your code never exits. Never use bare `except` statements.

Comment: You can see the exceptions. `import sys` then in your print, `print(sys.exc_info())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python sys.exit not working in try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905923/python-sys-exit-not-working-in-try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to catch all exceptions, as it sometimes may lead to unexpected behaviour and disguise real issues.
Having said that, the problem with your code is that `exit(0)` raises a `SystemExit` exception, that is inadvertently handled by the bare `except` in your code. If you really want to catch all exceptions, you can consider modifying your code like so:

```
    try:
    ...
except SystemExit:
    raise
except Exception:
    # handling
```

This should handle all exceptions except the one raised by `exit(0)`